# Geographic library for c#

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, geography

I'm programming an game app by c#. I want to calculate movement of objects in app screen. For example I want to know if my object move from a source to destination (using their `latitude` and `longitude`) with a `speed` and `direction` (and if possible `turn rate`), what is the destination point after a time.

in other words In need some thing like this:

```
void Move(double sourceLatitude, double sourceLongitude, double speed, double bearingOrDirection, double turnRate, double destinationLatitude, double destinationLongitude)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Is there any library that have this method or some things like this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This should be asked on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: GDAL might do what you want: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

Answer (score 1):

One must first convert latitude/longitude to an orthogonal coordinate system such as Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM). The corresponding velocity components in the orthogonal coordinate system are then calculated from the given heading. Using the time step, the change in position is calculated and added to the original coordinates. Lastly, the updated coordinates are converted back to latitude/longitude. In pseudo code:

```
(latitude_degN, longitude_degE) --> (easting_m, northing_m, utm_zone)
heading_rad += turn_rate_radps * timestep_s
east_velocity_mps = sin(heading_rad)
north_velocity_mps = cos(heading_rad)
delta_east_m = east_velocity_mps * timestep_s
delta_north_m = north_velocity_mps * timestep_s
easting_m += delta_east_m
northing_m += delta_north_m
(easting_m, northing_m, utm_zone) --> (latitude_degN, longitude_degE)
```

This assumes North-oriented heading (0 deg North, increasing to 90 deg East) and a small time step.